# MySQL in-place MINUS between two left-joins

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm familiar with the "LEFT JOIN/IS NULL" idiom to get the equivalent of a MINUS operator in MySQL.  Still, I've been trying to solve this one for a while without success (short of ugly sub-selects)

Here is a sample resultset to illustrate the problem:

```
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+
| group_id          | valid                                        | not_valid |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+
| favorites         | AD12,AD17,AD10,AD15,AD13,AD18,AD11,AD16,AD14 | NULL      |
| fruits_veggies    | AD13                                         | NULL      |
| pizza_grill       | AD12,AD10,AD21,AD19,AD11,AD22,AD20           | NULL      |
| salsa_wraps       | NULL                                         | NULL      |
| student_beverages | AD32,AD30,AD31                               | AD31,AD30 |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

In above, I want to remove any values from "valid" column that also exist in the "not_valid", so AD31, AD30 should be gone, leaving just the AD32, so a classic MINUS operator :)

Here is the SQL that gives me the above resultset. Any idea how to expand it to eliminate all not_valid SKUs from the valid SKUs?

```
select
    gm.group_id,
    group_concat(pt_include.sku) valid,
    group_concat(pt_exclude.sku) not_valid

from main_menu mm

    left join group_membership gm on 
        mm.master_account_id = gm.master_account_id
        and mm.group_id = gm.group_id

    left join product_tag pt_include on 
        mm.master_account_id = pt_include.master_account_id
        and gm.tag = pt_include.tag and gm.inclusive = '+'

    left join product_tag pt_exclude on 
        mm.master_account_id = pt_exclude.master_account_id
        and gm.tag = pt_exclude.tag and gm.inclusive = '-'

where 
    mm.master_account_id = 321
    and mm.menu_id = 987

group by gm.group_id
```

Follow up:

Below I stripped all other data for brevity. Consider that a product can be tagged X, Y, Z. The goal is to get back items tagged "X" & "Y", but not "Z". There can be any number of "inclusive" or "exclusive" tags. The user enters something like +X, +Y, -Z.

In our example, we want to get back all products marked as beverage, but exclude if beverage is 'teacher_only'. Thus, the two joins represented these two sets: first join all beverages, second join all beverages & teacher_only. Final result should be first-join MINUS second-join.

```
mysql> select * from main_menu;
+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| master_account_id | menu_id                | group_id          |
+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| FA32113145        | 1231                   | student_beverages |
+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------+

mysql> select * from group_membership;
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| master_account_id | group_id          | tag          | inclusive |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| FA32113145        | student_beverages | beverage     | +         |
| FA32113145        | student_beverages | teacher_only | -         |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+

mysql> select * from product_tag;
+-------------------+------+--------------+
| master_account_id | sku  | tag          |
+-------------------+------+--------------+
| FA32113145        | AD30 | beverage     |
| FA32113145        | AD30 | teacher_only |
| FA32113145        | AD31 | beverage     |
| FA32113145        | AD31 | teacher_only |
| FA32113145        | AD32 | beverage     |
+-------------------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: you're storing comma separated values in one field???

Comment: No, I'm merely illustrating the contents of the two sets, namely pt_include and pt_exclude, so you know which values I want to exclude from one another.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two joins for this.  Just use conditional aggregation.  `group_concat()` will ignore arguments that are `NULL`, so you can just use a `case` statement for tis:

```
select gm.group_id,
       group_concat(case when gm.inclusive = '+' then pt.sku end) as valid,
       group_concat(case when gm.inclusive = '-' then pt.sku end) as not_valid
from main_menu mm left join
     group_membership gm
     on mm.master_account_id = gm.master_account_id and
        mm.group_id = gm.group_id left join
     product_tag pt
     on mm.master_account_id = pt.master_account_id and
        gm.tag = pt.tag and gm.inclusive = '+'
where mm.master_account_id = 321 and
      mm.menu_id = 987
group by gm.group_id;
```

EDIT:

Oh, is the issue that you have tags with both types of tags, `-` and `+`, and in that case, you only want the tag in the `-` column.  I would approach this by aggregating by `sku` first, and then by the group:

```
select gm.group_id,
       group_concat(case when includeplus = 1 and includeminus = 0 then sku end) as valid,
       group_concat(case when includeminus = 1 then sku end) as invalid
from (select gm.group_id, pt.sku,
             max(gm.include = '+') then includeplus,
             max(gm.include = '-') then includeminus
      from main_menu mm left join
           group_membership gm
           on mm.master_account_id = gm.master_account_id and
              mm.group_id = gm.group_id left join
           product_tag pt
           on mm.master_account_id = pt.master_account_id and
              gm.tag = pt.tag and gm.inclusive = '+'
      where mm.master_account_id = 321 and
            mm.menu_id = 987
      group by gm.group_id, pt.sku
     ) g
group by gm.group_id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. A product can have (unlimited) tags, such as "beverage", "teacher_only", etc. What we want to get back is all products that are "beverage" minus "teacher_only". mysql> select * from product_tag;
+-------------------+------+--------------+
| account_id | sku  | tag                 |
+-------------------+------+--------------+
| 123        | AD30 | beverage            |
| 123        | AD31 | beverage            |
| 123        | AD32 | beverage            |
| 123        | AD30 | teacher_only        |
| 123        | AD31 | teacher_only        |

Comment: @Debriter . . . I don't understand your comment.  Can you edit your question with the data the produces your the given results?